# How to run tcpdump on Centos right after reboot?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, centos6, tcpdump

I see that my Amazon EC2 has a lot of traffic coming inbound after I reboot my Linux machine.
I would like to find out what is going on right after the servers comes back after reboot.

I thought using tcpdump to capture the traffic. how can I make sure the tcpdump starts right after reboot and write information to a file?

any other tools should I use maybe?

Thanks!!
Dotan.

Comment: Put it in rc.local (or the CentOS equivalent)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ntop](http://www.ntop.org/) is actually a better tool. It installs as a daemon and will work as soon as the machine boots. Has a bonus of being a continuous log and also has a nice web interface as it gathers data.

Comment: I installed it and I can get it to work whan I run "ntop" but when I run "service ntop start" I get Error Opening file ./GeoLiteCity.dat
Error Opening file ./GeoIPASNum.dat  any idea how I fix it (I googled it and made few changes but I still get the error....) Thanks!

Comment: Try `/usr/sbin/ntop` directly. It seems to be a bug but shouldn't stop it from starting.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can just use iptables -j LOG